# Aligning two extremely similar but slightly different videos

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, video-processing, similarity, semantic-segmentation

I have two videos of the Super Smash Brothers video game.  In one video, the characters exist.  In the other video, the characters do not exist.  Everything else about the videos are the exact same except the characters being invisible in one of them.

When I output the two videos, I have to manually align them in a video editor.  Once they are aligned, they stay in sync!  However, the videos have a random amount of start time which is the problem.

What's a good way to automatically align these two different but extremely similar videos?  Here are example frames.

[image]

[image: without characters]

Current ideas:
Take a random frame halfway through the video, compare to the other video at the same location.  Use Mean Squared Error between the pixels.  Move forward 5 seconds and back 5 seconds.  Take the frame with the smallest MSE difference and use that as the matching frame remove the offset from the longer video at the beginning.  This seems extremely brittle and slow.

Comment: why would this get downvoted

Comment: Most likely because your question is too broad (or in SO Newspeak: "Needs more focus") and does not provide a [mre]. Surely, you know: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example !?

Comment: How about looking at the time clock? The font and position are known, so you could use template matching. You could look for the moment the seconds digit changes to align the videos maybe.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's an excellent idea!  I could use OCR on a specific crop of the video to extract the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current idea is good, but it doesn't need to be slow at all. Since the different part of the images are only the fighters! and we can assume those fighters are always at the middle of the image, so you just need to match a little part of the images, like the rectangle I drew:

[image]

Besides you can use other fast matching methods too like ORB features.

Comment: With Smash we can't assume they're always in one location.   The can certainly be on the extremes of the screen. 
The other problem is that the compression makes what should be pixel perfect similarity slightly different.  I should fix that.
I'll do some research on ORB features!  I'm not familiar with the concept, so thanks!

Comment: @NateW Pick multiple small boxes in different parts of the image and do comparison on them (wherever they might be seen) and try other methods for difference checking like correlation coefficient. You want to find the best match, not the perfect match. this link helps: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html